In GetX, navigating between Screen A and B using Get.toNamed() doesn't trigger init() when returning to Screen A from Screen B. How to fix?
In GetX, when you navigate between two screens using Get.toNamed(), you might encounter an issue where the init() method of Screen A is not triggered when returning from Screen B. Here's a breakdown of the problem and the solution:
Scenario:
Screen A → Screen B: You use Get.toNamed() to navigate from Screen A to Screen B, passing arguments if necessary. This works fine.
Screen B → Screen A: When you're done with Screen B, you use Get.toNamed() again to return to Screen A, possibly with some arguments. However, when Screen A is shown again, its init() method (or equivalent, such as a controller.onInit() or initState() in a StatefulWidget) does not get called.
Get.offNamed('/screenA', arguments: {...});

class ScreenAController extends GetxController {
@override
 void onReady() {
  super.onReady();
  // Re-fetch or refresh data here
 }
}

we tried the above scenario

I though it have many reason and many solution for your problem
if you are use GetBuilder you can try to put global to false for prevent duplicate screen
and i don't know why you use Get.toNamed(...) to pop your screen you can use like
Get.pop() or Get.close(1) and then controller.onInit() if you want to return value back to screen A you can use Callback send in PopScope

It's like a nested navigation we are passing arguments to get the new data

then did set global to false work ? if not can you provide code of nested navigator ?
